# Space people forgot they are not space suits

Tags: story-identification

Looking for a book that included race of space people that basically forgot their true look. They live all their lives inside space suits with engines, and identify themselves with suits. Their real appearance is tabooed and known only to medical personnel.

The main storyline was about suits that controlled their wearers. The abovementioned race was connected with those suits somehow.

I checked SpacePeople, SpaceNomads and TranshumansInSpace on tvtropes, but did not find it.

Comment: In Bruce Sterling's story *Cicada Queen* the *Lobsters* are humans who live all their lives in space suits. Their real appearance isn't taboo though - they just don't care about it.

Comment: D~a~a~a~a~l~e~k.

Answer (score 5):

["The Garments of Caean" by Barrington J. Bayley.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Garments_of_Caean)

> "Metalloids" or "Suit Men" whose infant forms are placed in space suits, in which they inhabit their entire lives. In fact, their entire identity and self image is that of a completely robotic form. This race inhabits a small asteroid belt and the open space around it – which, in their suits – they are completely free to roam.